# ACF Insert Flexible Content with creation of post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am setting up default posts when my theme is installed.  It creates the post and returns the id but I have been unsuccessful in inserting the ACF Flexible Content.  They do not have any example code or information on inserting Flexible Content in their documentation.  I have created the code below but have been unsuccessful in my attempts.

```
$config=array(
    array(
        "type" => "menu",
        "subfields" => array(
            'field_589ad3b3b6ccf'=>'menu', // wrapper_class
            'field_589ad3b3b6cce'=>'menu', // wrapper_id
            'field_589ad402b6cd1'=>'7', // menu_type
            'field_59876063512cb'=>'left', // menu_alignment
            'field_589ad3dcb6cd0'=>'2', // menu_selection
            'field_589ad3b3b6ccd'=>'1' // menu_width
        ) 
    )
);
foreach($config as $field){
    // Create Menu field
    foreach ($field['subfields'] as $sub){
        // Create subfields
        add_row( 'page_builder', $sub, $headerID );
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: And you didn't see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/?

Comment: Obviously I have read that page.  If you would read that page it tells you how to pull from the Flexible Content not how to pragmatically add rows into it. Please Try again.

Comment: Please word your question appropriately. What you are trying to do is unclear. There is a difference between "inserting Flexible Content" and "inserting rows into Flexible Content". You might want to share screenshots of the backend and your flexible content setup.

Comment: @James did you ever figure out a solution to your question? I'm having a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: I did.  I just answered the question with what worked for me.  I have not tested it but it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to loop through an array of settings.

```
$items=array(
    array(
        'sub_type'=>'menu',
        'class'=>'menu',
        'id'=>'menu',
        'menu_type'=>'7',
        'menu_alignment'=>'left', 
        'menu_selection'=>'2'
        'menu_width'=>'1'
    )
);
$postID = wp_insert_post( $args );
$field_key = "field_5a9c3bcb8de8e";

foreach($items as $item){ 
    update_field( $field_key, $item, $postID );
}
```